# where i get alpha brushes for texture paint and sculpting for free?

Tags: texture-painting, sculpting

i have google this,but unfortunately there are a a lot of good ones but paid and some are packs for zbrush, some are images or files in zbrush format, so where can i get a lot of brushes with enough or high resolution in image format like png,jpg,tga,etc of anykind of textures like specificaly skin,rock,wood,scracthes,dirt,etc please post below ALL usefull links of brushes for this purpouse and if you have ones that you bought and its very good and usefull i would apreciate if you can it give to us for free.

Comment: Make them yourself with Blender by sculpting fine details and using procedural textures for microdisplacement, then render to your own texture at whatever resolution you need.

Comment: In 2.8 there is a BlenderKit addon and a website with some free brushes

Comment: https://www.blendswap.com/blend/18735

Answer (score 0):

You can download them from here for free.
https://pixologic.com/zbrush/downloadcenter/alpha/#prettyPhoto

Comment: Channel Could you add this link to a new section on theses posts so it doesn't get lost? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender Thanks